# Prevent simultaneous click on Imageviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 3 image views and I would like to prevent simultaneous taps on image views. how can I do that? Can anyone help me??

```
 for (int i=0; i <= [_images1 count]-1; i++){
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width/3;
    wordsImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [wordsImage setFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin+20, self.view.frame.size.height/3,self.view.frame.size.width/3.5 , self.view.frame.size.height/5)];
    [wordsImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: [_images1 objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [self.view addSubview:wordsImage];
    [wordsImage setTag:i];
    wordsImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:index_image:)];
    tapGesture1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [tapGesture1 setDelegate:self];

    [wordsImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
}
```

Comment: just set the userinteraction mode = no for selection image

Comment: how to set it using tag value

Comment: check my answer @Bharathi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevents simultaneous click on Imageviews, you can set `exclusiveTouch` by `YES`.

```
/* exclusiveTouch
    A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver handles touch events exclusively.
    Setting this property to YES causes the receiver to block the delivery of touch events to other views in the same window. The default value of this property is NO.
*/
    for (int i=0; i <= [_images1 count]-1; i++){
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width/3;
        wordsImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        [wordsImage setFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin+20, self.view.frame.size.height/3,self.view.frame.size.width/3.5 , self.view.frame.size.height/5)];
        [wordsImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: [_images1 objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [self.view addSubview:wordsImage];
        [wordsImage setTag:i];
        wordsImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        wordsImage.exclusiveTouch = YES;//Set this property

        tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:index_image:)];
        tapGesture1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

        [tapGesture1 setDelegate:self];

        [wordsImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
    }
```

I hope this would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to restrict the sequence of click your same imageview. I hope this will help you.

```
    int  previousTag,curentTag,flag;
-(void)tapGesture:(id)sender{
    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

    if(flag == 0){
        previousTag = imageView.tag;
        curentTag = 520;  // unequal value you will enter here
        flag = 1;
    }
    else {
        curentTag = imageView.tag;
    }

    if(previousTag != curentTag)
    {
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"]];
        previousTag = curentTag;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

W hen you tap the image view set one `Bool` variable to `true` and manage that variable.